# C# Interacting with ModelVisual3D objects in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit

Hey I am using a WPF 3D scene and successfully loaded a few .stl models into it.
I am basicall using a method to select and deselect these objects, based on where my mouse in the windows is:

```
 private void UIElement_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var viewport = (HelixViewport3D)sender;
            var firstHit = viewport.Viewport.FindHits(e.GetPosition(viewport)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (firstHit != null)
            {
                this.viewModel.Select(firstHit.Visual);

            }
            else
            {
                this.viewModel.Select(null);

            }
        }
```

So I have the selected ModelVisual3D and could store it. However here is the main problem:

My models are generated based on certain data and an associated .stl model.
Basicall I import the .stl model and show it in my 3D scene, but the problem is I have no idea how connect my other data to the model.

For example when I select the visual, I want to show another windows with information like: material, dimensions, company.

But I can't figure out how to determine, which unique ModelVisual3D object is selected at the moment. There seem to be no properties I could use to my advantage doing something like:

```
ModelImporter tr = new ModelImporter();
            var model = tr.Load("C:\\Users\\...\\Pictures\\a.stl");
            ModelVisual3D test = new ModelVisual3D();

            test.Content = model;

//Here I would like to save the id of my visual model to identify and
//associate it with my other data later

            int myUniqueModelID=test.Properties.UNIQUEID
```

Comment: Is your other "data" in a separate object?

Answer (score 0):

What about using a dictionary to keep the mapping between your data reference and `ModelVisual3D` reference.

Like

```
    Dictionary<ModelVisual3D, StlDataObject> modelDataMap = new Dictionary<ModelVisual3D, StlDataObject>();
    public void LoadModelWithData(string dataFilePath, string stlModelPath)
    {
        ModelImporter tr = new ModelImporter();
        var model = tr.Load("C:\\Users\\...\\Pictures\\a.stl");
        ModelVisual3D test = new ModelVisual3D();

        test.Content = model;

        //Load the datafile from file (or pass it this method)
        StlDataObject IdForOurStlModel = GetStlDataFromFile(dataFilePath);
        modelDataMap.Add(test, IdForOurStlModel);
    }
```

Then when you need to find your data from the hit test in your viewport, you just check if this dictionary contains a key for the pressed `ModelVisual3d` and return the value related to that key if it does.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution thanks! But how would I " just check if this dictionary contains a key for the pressed ModelVisual3d" ? Sorry I am not that familiar with dictionaries and since I have no ID I do not know how to check something in a way like if(id=1){ do...}

Comment: The instance' GetHashCode becomes the ID when you add the instance as the Key if i'm not mistaken :) This means you could do `if(modelDataMap.Contains(test))` to check if its in the dictionary as well as `modelDataMap[test]` to retrieve the data